# JavaFX dependency on video card

Tags: direct3d, javafx-3d

Is there any video card related dependency in JavaFX? The main issue is that I am getting an error on my application whenever I am trying to process a large images. We turned verbose logging on for Prism, and discovered that the reason for this discrepancy is that Prism fails to load Direct3D when run inside a Windows service, and is forced to fall back on its software rendering pipeline instead of using hardware acceleration.

Here's the relevant part of the log:

> Direct3D initialization failed
>   Adapter validation failed for all adapters
>   (X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
>   GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
>   *** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline

Comment: You are "getting an error on my application whenever I am trying to process a large images".  What error?  -> include a stack trace.  What is the processing code?  -> include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which somebody could compile and run to replicate the error.  Include the image furnishing the error. You can post it on https://imgur.com if you don't have the ability to inline it in your question due to reputation limits.

Comment: Googling for "Direct3D service" returns [that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/978635/direct3d-9-is-not-supported-in-the-context-of-a-windows-service) as first result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware based acceleration requires [supported hardware](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) for it to work.  If supported hardware is not available, the system will fall back to software rendering (which is exactly what the log you showed says).  Either way JavaFX will work.

Without hardware acceleration some features may be disabled (see [`ConditionalFeature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html)).

Unless you are attempting to use features which are not enabled on your system (you can check it code using [`Platform.isSupported`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#isSupported-javafx.application.ConditionalFeature-)) or you are relying on the increased processing speed provided by hardware acceleration, then your application is unlikely to be impacted by running on a software rendering pipeline rather than a hardware rendering pipeline.